# Installed Korean fonts in Apple Font Book all have "동" where in English we would have "Aa"—why?

Tags: vocabulary, korean-culture

[image: Screenshot of installed Korean fonts in a Mac UI]

[image]

Installed Korean fonts in Apple Font Book all have "동" where in English we would have "Aa"—why? And is the meaning here "east" or something else?

Comment: just looks like a random placeholder graphic for preview

Comment: Sure but why ‘동‘? Someone landed on that for some reason

Comment: Might be the first character of a random sentence beginning with “동쪽 …,” or likely, the national anthem “동해 물과 백두산이…,” which is common practice in Korean font-making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the first example texts in Korean fonts are the Korean national anthem, which starts with: 
 동해 물과 백두산이 마르고 닳도록

The first letter '동' is shown in icon.

Comment: "Probably because the first example texts in Korean fonts are the Korean national anthem" Do you have any source for this claim?

Comment: I second this. The first few lines of the Korean national anthem is the Korean “Lorem ipsum.” There isn’t any official _source_ for this. There cannot be, because it’s _observation_ of the common practice.

Comment: @КонстантинВан then are there any links to pictures or screenshots showing this?

Comment: @user17915 Search result for 'Mac Korean font' in Google image search yields several examples. I brought the link of first result. https://discussion.enpass.io/uploads/monthly_2021_01/1492971657_2021-01-089_58_18.png.7f643a9e5d7867f736d73a7dc22c4799.png

Comment: Is this trend mostly in mac computers or something?

Comment: I've seen examples like those only in mac. Windows (after Vista) uses '다람쥐 헌 쳇바퀴에 타고파'. Google Chrome browser uses '정 참판 양반댁 규수 큰 교자 타고 혼례 치른 날'. Naver Whale browser uses '추운 겨울에는 따뜻한 커피와 티를 마셔야지요'.